How to share session cookie between a Koa app and Experss app?
I have an API built using Koa v2 and we have a cookie session based authentication. For that, we use the koa-session library and it works. But now, we are migrating our API to NestJS, using express as the server adapter and we are doing it incrementally, so we need to have both APIs working at the same time, the koa one under a v1 prefix and the NestJS one under a v2 prefix, and that's already working.
The main issue here is that for express, I'm using the express-session library, which has a different implementation than the koa library, mainly the cookie that is set is not just the session id. For both I'm already using a database store, so I can save and retrieve the session from the database for both APIs, but if I login in v1, the session does not work for v2 and vice-versa.
Is there a library that works for both or at least, a way of making the koa-session to work on express?
This is my koa-session config:
const sessionConfig: Partial<session.opts> = {
  key: 'session' /** (string) cookie key (default is koa.sess) */,
  /** (number || 'session') maxAge in ms (default is 1 days) */
  /** 'session' will result in a cookie that expires when session/browser is closed */
  maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  overwrite: true /** (boolean) can overwrite or not (default true) */,
  httpOnly: true /** (boolean) httpOnly or not (default true) */,
  signed: true /** (boolean) signed or not (default true) */,
  rolling: false /** (boolean) Force a session identifier cookie to be set on every response. The expiration is reset to the original maxAge, resetting the expiration countdown. (default is false) */,
  renew: true /** (boolean) renew session when session is nearly expired, so we can always keep user logged in. (default is false) */,
  secure: !['test'].includes(stage) /** (boolean) secure cookie */,
  sameSite: ['production', 'test'].includes(stage)
    ? <const>'lax'
    : <const>'none' /** (string) sameSite options (default null) */,
  store: {
    get: pgsession.get,
    set: pgsession.set,
    destroy: pgsession.destroy,
  },
};

This is my express-session config:
session({
  secret,
  name: 'session',
  cookie: {
    maxAge,
    sameSite: ['production', 'test'].includes(stage)
      ? <const>'lax'
      : <const>'none' /** (string) sameSite options (default null) */,
    httpOnly: true,
    signed: true,
    secure: !['test', 'local'].includes(stage),
  },
  rolling: false /** (boolean) Force a session identifier cookie to be set on every response. The expiration is reset to the original maxAge, resetting the expiration countdown. (default is false) */,
  store: new PostgresSession(),
  genid: () => {
    return uuid.v4();
  },
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
})


After studying both libraries, I've found that this is not possible. The solution is to either implement your own session middleware for both, or in my case, I forked the express-session library, and removed the code that signs the session id (because for some reason you can't disable this) and disabled the sign process for koa-session, resulting in both using the same cookie data.
